# I am getting an error when I try to run my react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The error is coming from the first line of my App.js file I am getting an error on the first line when I try to import react. I have made sure that all dependencies are installed and I have also restarted vs code .

Uncaught SyntaxError c:\Users\Dell i7\react-category-v1\src\App.js:1
import React from 'react'

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'


import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Reports from './pages/Reports';
import Products from './pages/Products';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
        
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What are you doing to "run" your project ?

Comment: I am clicking on run/debug in vs code

Comment: in your terminal run  `npm run dev`, and make sure the dev script is defined in your package.json file.

Answer (score -1):

use Routes instead of Switch, i think Switch is no longer available. if you are using latest version of react-route-dom

```
<Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Home/>
     <Routes>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
       </Routes>
    </Router>
```

Comment: How can you say this is the definitive answer if you don't know the version of react router they're running?

Comment: "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.3",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "router-dom": "^2.2.9",